# Monitor screen resolution changes when laptop lid is closed

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, display, resolution

My monitor screen resolution changes depending on wether my laptop lid is open/closed.
The lid being open has a lower resolution than being closed. Why is this ?

In control panel I have :

[image]

Laptop lid open :
[image]

Laptop lid closed : 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you choose to `Duplicate these displays`, your computer has to choose a resolution that is supported by both displays.

If you cannot choose a higher resolution with the lid open, it means that `1024 x 768` is the highest resolution supported by your internal display. Obviously, this restriction does not apply when using only the external monitor.